# maxAge must be either -1, 0, or a positive integer: -2147483648

Tags: java, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I was trying to test my Play app using fakeApplication and FakeRequest() from play test API.

The code looks like:

```
    running(fakeApplication(extraConfig, settings),() ->
         {
            Map<String, String> body = new HashMap();
            body.put("login", "login");
            body.put("password", "password");
            // Arrange
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest(POST, "/login")
                    .withSession("user_id", "1")
                    .withCookies(new Http.Cookie("1", "1", 125, null, null, false, false)).withFormUrlEncodedBody(body)
                    ;

            // Act
            Result result = route(request);}
```

No matter how I compose my request(with cookies, without cookies, empty altogether) is't always the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxAge must be either -1, 0, or a positive integer: -2147483648
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultCookie.setMaxAge(DefaultCookie.java:185)
    at play.api.mvc.Cookies$$anonfun$10.apply(Http.scala:733)
    at play.api.mvc.Cookies$$anonfun$10.apply(Http.scala:730)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.map(Stream.scala:376)
    at play.api.mvc.Cookies$.encode(Http.scala:730)
    at play.api.mvc.Cookies$.merge(Http.scala:781)
    at play.api.test.FakeRequest.withSession(Fakes.scala:97)
    at play.test.FakeRequest.withSession(FakeRequest.java:131).....
```

The only thing that differs sometimes is this "positive number" -2147483648.

I'm really stuck here. There are so many different variations of the application set-up(using Scala, using Java, Using Play2.0.X, 2.1, 2.2, etc.). The snippet I provide here doesn't work on my Play 2.3.7/Java no matter what I do.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Did you notice lambda in my code?:)

Comment: Read the error message like this: maxAge must be either -1, 0, or a positive integer: However the value you provided was -2147483648. Looks like you must set maxAge of the cookie, but you dont

Comment: Looks like an overflow as 2147483648 is 2^31.

Comment: Yeh, I see what you mean but I can't find how I can set it properly for FakeApplication. The third param in Cookie() is supposed to be maxAge, but it doesn't help. I played with the API for a while and is failing to set maxAge so far.

Comment: For empty FakeRequest the stack is as follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxAge must be either -1, 0, or a positive integer: -86400